# How to override release in ARC?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

How can I override release method in ARC?
I need it just for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't.  Fiddling with the memory management routines will likely cause you no end of trouble.

If you're dealing with an over-release (which it sounds like), you should learn to use Instruments instead.  That will tell you exactly when all the `-release` calls are happening, and where they're coming from.

Comment: Specifically, the "Zombies" instrument template.